# Find nested hierarchies using boolean matrix

Tags: c#, tree, nested, hierarchical-trees

I have a created a Node Builder to fetch how n elements are connected to one another. It is a parent child hierarchy represented in Node Tree.

I am using tree builder like below code to find best two chains.

Below is the code:

```
public class NodeBuilder
    {
        private readonly List<IItem> _nestedItems;
        private readonly IFactory<IItem> _factory;
        private readonly NodeEqualityComparer _comparer;
        private readonly List<Node> _nodes;
        private WeightedComparer _weightedComparer;
        private NodeComparer _nodeComparer;
        private readonly NodeItemComparer _nodeItemComparer;

        public NodeBuilder(List<IItem> nestedItems, IFactory<IItem> factory)
        {
            _nestedItems = nestedItems;
            _factory = factory;
            _comparer = new NodeEqualityComparer();
            _nodeComparer = new NodeComparer();
            _nodes = new List<Node>();
            _weightedComparer=new WeightedComparer();
            _nodeItemComparer = new NodeItemComparer(_factory.Comparer);
        }

        public IEnumerable<List<int>> GetTopChains(int collections)
        {
            if (_nodes.Count == 0) BuildNodes(collections);

            var collection= GetIndexes().ToList();
            collection.Sort(_weightedComparer);
            return collection.Take(collections);
        }

        public class WeightedComparer : IComparer<List<int>>
        {
            public int Compare(List<int> x, List<int> y)
            {
                if (x == y) return 0;
                if (x == null) return 1;
                if (y == null) return -1;
                return y.Count - x.Count;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<List<int>> GetIndexes()
        {
            Dictionary<IItem,List<int>> indexers = new Dictionary<IItem, List<int>>();
            _nodes.Sort(_nodeItemComparer);
            foreach (var node in _nodes)
            {
                List< int> indexs=new List<int>();
                int currSize = node.ChainSize;
                var temp = node;
                while (temp != null)
                {
                    int index = _nestedItems.IndexOf(temp.Item);
                    if (index != -1) indexs.Add(index);
                    currSize--;
                    var temps = new List<Node>(temp.Childs.Where(x => x.ChainSize == currSize));
                    temps.Sort(_nodeComparer);
                    Dictionary<Node,List<int>> subIndexes = new Dictionary<Node, List<int>>();
                    if (!temps.Any()) temp = null;
                    foreach (var subTemp in temps)
                    {

                        var key = subTemp.Item;
                        if (indexers.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            var newList = new List<int>();
                            newList.AddRange(indexs);
                            newList.AddRange(indexers[key]);
                            subIndexes.Add(subTemp, newList);
                        }

                        if (subIndexes[subTemp].Count == node.ChainSize)
                        {
                            temp = subTemp;
                            indexers.Remove(subTemp.Item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp = null;
                        }

                    }


                }
                indexs = indexs.Distinct().ToList();
                indexers.Add(node.Item,indexs);
            }


            return indexers.Values;
        }

        private void BuildNodes(int collections)
        {
            int total = _factory.TotalItems;
            for (int i = collections * _factory.TotalItems - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var searchNode = new Node(_nestedItems[i], _factory.EqualityComparer);
                Node node1 = _nodes.SingleOrDefault(x => _comparer.Equals(x, searchNode));
                if (node1 == null)
                {
                    node1 = searchNode;
                    node1.ChainSize = total;
                    _nodes.Add(node1);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < collections * _factory.TotalItems; i++)
            {
                var searchNode = new Node(_nestedItems[i], _factory.EqualityComparer);
                Node node1 = _nodes.SingleOrDefault(x => _comparer.Equals(x, searchNode));

                for (int j = 0; j < collections * _factory.TotalItems; j++)
                {
                    searchNode = new Node(_nestedItems[j], _factory.EqualityComparer);
                    Node node2 = _nodes.SingleOrDefault(x => _comparer.Equals(x, searchNode));
                    if (node2 == null)
                    {
                        node2 = searchNode;
                        _nodes.Add(node2);
                    }
                    if (_nestedItems[i].Constraint(_nestedItems[j]))
                    {
                        if (node1 != null)
                        {
                            int temp = node1.ChainSize - 1;
                            node2.ChainSize = temp;`enter code here`
                            if (!node1.Childs.Contains(node2, new NodeEqualityComparer()))
                                node1.Childs.Add(node2);
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class NodeItemComparer:IComparer<Node>
    {
        private readonly IComparer<IItem> _factoryComparer;

        public NodeItemComparer(IComparer<IItem> factoryComparer)
        {
            _factoryComparer = factoryComparer;
        }

        public int Compare(Node x, Node y)
        {
            if (x == null & y == null) return 0;
            if (x == y) return 0;
            if (x == null) return 1;
            if (y == null) return -1;
            return _factoryComparer.Compare(y.Item, x.Item);
        }
    }

    public class NodeComparer:IComparer<Node>
    {
        public int Compare(Node x, Node y)
        {
            if (x == null & y == null) return 0;
            if (x == y) return 0;
            if (x == null) return 1;
            if (y == null) return -1;
            return y.ChainSize - x.ChainSize;
        }
    }

    public class NodeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Node>
    {
        public bool Equals(Node x, Node y)
        {
            if (x == null & y == null) return true;
            if (x == y) return true;
            if (x != y) return false;
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Node obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class Node : IEquatable<Node>
    {
        public IItem Item { get; }

        private readonly IEqualityComparer<IItem> _comparer;
        public int ChainSize { get; set; }


        public IList<Node> Childs { get; private set; }



        public Node(IItem item, IEqualityComparer<IItem> comparer)
        {
            Item = item;

            _comparer = comparer;


            Childs = new List<Node>();
        }



        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Item.ItemName;
        }

        public bool Equals(Node other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return _comparer.Equals(Item, other.Item);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Node)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Item != null ? Item.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Node left, Node right)
        {
            return Equals(left, right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Node left, Node right)
        {
            return !Equals(left, right);
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a ways to traverse the tree and find two hierarchical connected items.